# Java for-each on getter

Tags: java, gwt, foreach, getter

If javac do what I think, the following lines would yield the same performance:

```
for (Object o: getObjects()) {}
List<Object> os = getObjects(); for (Object o: os) {}
```

Is it so or not? Or is it perhaps implementation-specific? If so: anybody know about GWT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These answers all seem correct from a pure Java perspective. Furthermore, if it can, the GWT compiler will actually rewrite the enhanced for loop further, into a regular for loop before it generates the JavaScript.  So it will actually end up looking something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getObjects().size(); i++) {
  Object o = getObjects().get(i);
  // ...
}
```

The reason?  If the List iterator object is never referenced, it can be declared as dead code and won't be rewritten in JavaScript, resulting in a smaller download size.  This optimization should have no effect whatsoever on the actual execution of your code.

See [Optimizing apps with the GWT compiler](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qT6ZsQBM7kY), from this year's Google I/O, for more details about other crazy things the GWT compiler does to reduce JS size.

Answer (score 8):

From the Java Language Specifications:

> #### [14.14.2 The enhanced for statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.2)
>
> The enhanced for statement has the
>   form:
>
> ```
> EnhancedForStatement:
>         for ( VariableModifiersopt Type Identifier: Expression) Statement
> ```
>
> The Expression must either have type
>   `Iterable` or else it must be of an
>   array type (§10.1), or a compile-time
>   error occurs.
>
> The scope of a local variable declared
>   in the FormalParameter part of an
>   enhanced `for` statement (§14.14) is
>   the contained Statement
>
> The meaning of the enhanced `for`
>   statement is given by translation into
>   a basic `for` statement.
>
> If the type of *`Expression`* is a
>   subtype of `Iterable`, then let *`I`* be
>   the type of the expression
>   *Expression.*`iterator()`. The enhanced `for` statement is equivalent
>   to a basic `for` statement of the
>   form:
>
> ```
> for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
>
>         VariableModifiersopt Type Identifier = #i.next();
>    Statement
> }
> ```
>
> Where *`#i`* is a compiler-generated
>   identifier that is distinct from any
>   other identifiers (compiler-generated
>   or otherwise) that are in scope (§6.3)
>   at the point where the enhanced for
>   statement occurs.

As you can see, *`Expression`* is mentioned only in the first part of the for loop expression and is thus only evaluated once. So your two lines would yield the same performance.

Answer (score 7):

The performance will be identical.

The Java compiler turns for-each loops into a loop around an `Iterator` object by calling the `iterator()` method on the object that you loop over.
Therefore, the actual list instance is only used once.  (To call `iterator()`)

Answer (score 4):

From a practical point of view you can inspect both bytecodes and compare them:

```
 m1()V
   L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKEVIRTUAL it/funge/Console.getObjects()Ljava/util/List;
    INVOKEINTERFACE java/util/List.iterator()Ljava/util/Iterator;
    ASTORE 2
    GOTO L1
   L2
   FRAME FULL [it/funge/Console T java/util/Iterator] []
    ALOAD 2
    INVOKEINTERFACE java/util/Iterator.next()Ljava/lang/Object;
    ASTORE 1
   L1
   FRAME SAME
    ALOAD 2
    INVOKEINTERFACE java/util/Iterator.hasNext()Z
    IFNE L2
   L3
    RETURN

m2()V
   L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKEVIRTUAL it/funge/Console.getObjects()Ljava/util/List;
    ASTORE 1
   L1
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKEINTERFACE java/util/List.iterator()Ljava/util/Iterator;
    ASTORE 3
    GOTO L2
   L3
   FRAME FULL [it/funge/Console java/util/List T java/util/Iterator] []
    ALOAD 3
    INVOKEINTERFACE java/util/Iterator.next()Ljava/lang/Object;
    ASTORE 2
   L2
   FRAME SAME
    ALOAD 3
    INVOKEINTERFACE java/util/Iterator.hasNext()Z
    IFNE L3
   L4
    RETURN
```

They are equal, the only difference is that your second snippet has two separate parts to load the `List` and then obtain the iterator. This will also consume more locals of the class, infact it has also an `ALOAD` and an `ASTORE` more, it is used to store `getObjects` result through the two lines of code while in your first snippet it directly uses it..

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference. The foreach construct just fetches an `Iterator` from the object. That's why it has to implement the [`Iterable`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface.